# jqGrid make rowNum depend on vertical grid y-size

Tags: jqgrid, rownum

I have jqGrid which size is dynamically calculated on window resize as follows:

```
$(window).bind('resize', resizeTable);
function resizeTable(){
    $("#jqGrid")
        .setGridWidth($("#tableHolder").innerWidth()),
        .setGridHeight($("#tableHolder").innerHeight());
};
```

Having constant rowNum, scroll bar appears on grid if y-size isn't enough to hold given number of rows.

I want rowNum to be calculated automatically to display only rows which fit in a visible area of the grid and make others move to next pages and have no scroll bar. Is that possible?

Comment: Please post your code or images to explain more your problem.
what is currently behavior. and
what you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't included in your question *how* you calculate the size based on on window resize and which more important **which options** of jqGrid you set and when you set (in which callback/event).

In general one can either set `height` or `rowNum`. I personally prefer to specify `rowNum` (which value could be calculated based on the window resize) and to use `height: "auto"`, which is default value of `height` in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). As the result, the grid will never have vertical scroll bars.

Additionally I prefer to use top pager (`toppager: true`) instead of the botom pager (`pager` option) if the height of rows of the grid could be *variable*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had hoped there are some built in functionality to make it easier, but `height: "auto"` and set `rowNum` is a good point. By the way is there an easy way to get row height?

Comment: @VictorK.: You should describe what you do more detailed. If you load the data from the server and the long text is wrapped or the text contains new lines (`\n`), then you can't guess or predict the height. It's enough to make one test and to examine the height of the *typical* row. You can use the value in your calculations of the value of `rowNum`.